# Значение типа "int *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "int"

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

У меня есть двумерный динамический массив. Массив заполняю ГПСЧ. Нужно пузырьком отсортировать элементы. Написал цикл, в котором должно происходить это. Но столкнулся с некоторой проблемой. 
В самом цикле, если сортировку делать так, как это пытаюсь сделать я, то возникает проблема:
matrix[i][j], а у меня в сортировке matrix[j]. От этого получаю ошибки, которые ниже.
Как это можно исправить?

Ошибки:

```
50 строка) значение типа "int *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "int"   
52 строка) значение типа "int" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "int *"
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void Border();

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");

    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));

    Border();
    int N, M, predV, predN, temp;
    cout << " Введите размер матрицы. \n\n";
    cout << " Введите количество строк > ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << " Введите количество рядов > ";
    cin >> M;
    cout << " Введите целое число максимального предела генерации > ";
    cin >> predV;
    cout << " Введите целое число минимального предела генерации > ";
    cin >> predN;
    Border();
    cout << endl;

    int** matrix = new int* [N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        matrix[i] = new int[M];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % predV + predN; // формула генерации от нижнего предела до верхнего]

    Border();
    cout << "Вывод матрицы. " << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }
    Border();

    // сортировка пузырьком по возрастанию
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M - i - 1; j++) {
            if (matrix[j] > matrix[j + 1]) {
                // меняю элементы местами
                temp = matrix[j];
                matrix[j] = matrix[j + 1];
                matrix[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    Border();
    cout << "Вывод отсортированной матрицы. " << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }
    Border();

    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        delete[] matrix[i];
    delete[] matrix;

    return 0;
}

void Border()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout << "=";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Обменивайте значения в строках в цикле.

Comment: "Нужно пузырьком отсортировать элементы." - элементы чего?

Comment: Забыли указать номер строки при обмене. Вы сравниваете указатели строк и хотите их поменять. А надо элементы `matrix[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полностью изменил логику. Теперь сортировка происходит аналогично сортировке одномерного массива.

Перебор элементов происходит по очереди, начиная с `matrix[0][1]`. Затем в двойном вложенном цикле вывожу двухмерный массив (типа вывожу). Сравниваю с предыдущим.
`i=inext`, `j=jnext`. В роли индекса предыдущего - значение, которое зафиксировано на предыдущей итерации цикла.

```
int inext, jnext;
    int i, j;
    int temp;
    bool sorted = false;
    while (!sorted) {
        sorted = true;
        i = 0; j = 0;
        for (inext = 0; inext < N; inext++)
            for (jnext = (inext ? 0 : 1); jnext < M; jnext++)
            {
                if (matrix[i][j] > matrix[inext][jnext]) {
                    temp = matrix[i][j];
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix[inext][jnext];
                    matrix[inext][jnext] = temp;
                    sorted = false;
                }
                i = inext;
                j = jnext;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> temp = matrix[j];
> ```

```
int *temp = matrix[j];
```

А ещё вот тут ошибка:

> ```
> matrix[i][j] = rand() % predV + predN;
> ```

```
matrix[i][j] = rand() % (predV - predN) + predN;
```